# import a csv file into MySQL workbench invalid path

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I try to import files using a *.csv file named import personen.csv
when i run this i get an error and the log displays an other path? how can i change this?

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 
'C:\Users\ava\Documents\2_School\1_Informatik\M141\importPersonen.csv' INTO 
TABLE persons
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' (PiD, Anrede, Name, Vorname, Adresse, Jahrgang, OiD);
```

this its ther error i get :

```
Error Code: 29. File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\UsersavaDocuments2_School1_InformatikM141importPersonen.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I did already change the my.ini file line to this secure-file-priv="" to import from everywhere

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Did you try the changing backward slashes to forward slashes?

Comment: @RahulChawla that do you mean exactly?

Comment: `'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\UsersavaDocuments2_School1_InformatikM141importPersonen.csv'`

to

`'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data/UsersavaDocuments2_School1_InformatikM141importPersonen.csv'`

Comment: this gets me the same error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: @RahulChawla Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
this is what i get with this so i guess without the local it should work but is doesen't...

Comment: On my windows box I have to use double forward slashes (\\).

Comment: That did allsow not work